# Api middleware with redux-observable

Tags: redux, rxjs, redux-thunk, reactivex, redux-observable

I'm refactoring my react/redux app to use `redux-observable` instead of `redux-thunk`.  Using thunk, I have an api middleware set up to listen for any actions with a `CALL_API` key and do some manipulation of the data, prepare headers, prepare full url, perform an api call using `axios`, and also do some additional action dispatches related to an api call.

Importantly, the api middleware dispatches a `REQUEST_START` action which gives the request an id and sets its status to `pending` in the `network` part of my state. When the promise from `axios` resolves or rejects, the middleware dispatches a `REQUEST_END` action, updating the state so that the current request is set to `resolved` or `rejected`.  Then the response is returned to the calling action creator that initially dispatched the `CALL_API` action.

I have not been able to figure out how to do this with `redux-observable`.  The part about the api middleware described above that I want to replicate is the `REQUEST_START` and `REQUEST_END` action dispatches. It's very convenient to have a centralized place where all api call related stuff is handled.  I know I can effectively dispatch the `REQUEST_START` and `REQUEST_END` actions in each of my epics that does an api call, but I don't want to have to repeat the same code in many places.

I managed to partially solve this by creating an `apiCallEpic` which listens for actions with type `CALL_API` and does the above setup for api calls.  However, an issue (or rather, something I don't like) is  that the epic that initiates the api call (e.g. `getCurrentUserEpic`) essentially gives up control to `apiCallEpic`.

So, for example, when the api call succeeds and has a response, I may want to format that response data in some way before dispatching an action to be handled by my reducer. That is, `getCurrentUserEpic` should do some formatting of data returned from api call before sending to reducer.  I was able to achieve something close to this by passing a `payloadHandler` callback function defined in `getCurrentUserEpic` that the `apiCallEpic` can call if/when it gets a successful response. However, I don't like this callback architecture and it seems like there's got to be a better way.

Here is some code that demonstrates my use of api middleware using thunk.

```
import axios from 'axios';


// actionCreators.js

// action types
const CALL_API = "CALL_API";
const FETCH_CURRENT_USER = "FETCH_CURRENT_USER";
const RECEIVE_CURRENT_USER = "RECEIVE_CURRENT_USER";

// action creators for request start and end
export const reqStart = (params = {}) => (dispatch) => {
  const reduxAction = {
    type: REQ_START,
    status: 'pending',
    statusCode: null,
    requestId: params.requestId,
  }
  dispatch(reduxAction);
}

export const reqEnd = (params = {}) => (dispatch) => {
  const {
    requestId,
    response = null,
    error = null,
  } = params;

  let reduxAction = {}

  if (response) {
    reduxAction = {
      type: REQ_END,
      status: 'success',
      statusCode: response.status,
      requestId,
    }
  }
  else if (error) {
    if (error.response) {
      reduxAction = {
        type: REQ_END,
        status: 'failed',
        statusCode: error.response.status,
        requestId,
      }
    }
    else {
      reduxAction = {
        type: REQ_END,
        status: 'failed',
        statusCode: 500,
        requestId,
      }
    }
  }
  dispatch(reduxAction);
}

// some api call to fetch data
export const fetchCurrentUser = (params = {}) => (dispatch) => {
  const config = {
    url: '/current_user',
    method: 'get',
  }

  const apiCall = {
    [CALL_API]: {
      config,
      requestId: FETCH_CURRENT_USER,
    }
  }

  return dispatch(apiCall)
  .then(response => {
    dispatch({
      type: RECEIVE_CURRENT_USER,
      payload: {response},
    })
    return Promise.resolve({response});
  })
  .catch(error => {
    return Promise.reject({error});
  })
}




// apiMiddleware.js

// api endpoint
const API_ENTRY = "https://my-api.com";

// utility functions for request preparation
export const makeFullUrl = (params) => {
  // ...prepend endpoint url with API_ENTRY constant
  return fullUrl
}

export const makeHeaders = (params) => {
  // ...add auth token to headers, etc.
  return headers;
}


export default store => next => action => {
  const call = action[CALL_API];

  if (call === undefined) {
    return next(action);
  }

  const requestId = call.requestId;

  store.dispatch(reqStart({requestId}));

  const config = {
    ...call.config, 
    url: makeFullUrl(call.config),
    headers: makeHeaders(call.config);
  }

  return axios(config)
  .then(response => {
    store.dispatch(reqEnd({
      response,
      requestId,
    }))
    return Promise.resolve(response);
  })
  .catch(error => {
    store.dispatch(reqEnd({
      error,
      requestId,
    }))
    return Promise.reject(error);
  })
}


// reducers.js

// Not included, but you can imagine reducers handle the
// above defined action types and update the state
// accordingly. Most usefully, components can always
// subscribe to specific api calls and check the request
// status.  Showing loading indicators is one
// use case.
```

Here's the code I've implemented to accomplish a similar thing with `redux-observable`.

```
export const fetchCurrentUserEpic = (action$, state$) => {
  const requestType = FETCH_CURRENT_USER;
  const successType = RECEIVE_CURRENT_USER;
  const requestConfig = {
    url: "/current_user",
    method: "get",
  }
  const payload = {requestConfig, requestType, successType};
  const payloadNormalizer = ({response}) => {
    return {currentUser: response.data.data};
  }

  return action$.ofType(FETCH_CURRENT_USER).pipe(
    switchMap((action) => of({
      type: CALL_API,
      payload: {...payload, requestId: action.requestId, shouldFail: action.shouldFail, payloadNormalizer},
    })),
  )
}

export const apiEpic = (action$, state$) => {
  return action$.ofType(CALL_API).pipe(
    mergeMap((action) => (
      concat(
        of({type: REQ_START, payload: {requestId: action.payload.requestId, requestType: action.payload.requestType}}),
        from(callApi(action.payload.requestConfig, action.payload.shouldFail)).pipe(
            map(response => {
              return {
                type: action.payload.successType,
                payload: action.payload.payloadNormalizer({response})
              }
            }),
            map(() => {
              return {
                type: REQ_END,
                payload: {status: 'success', requestId: action.payload.requestId, requestType: action.payload.requestType},
              }
           })
          )
        )
      ).pipe(
        catchError(error => {
          console.log('error', error);
          return of({type: REQ_END, payload: {status: 'failed', requestId: action.payload.requestId, requestType: action.payload.requestType}, error});
        })
      )
    )
  )
}
```

Any comments or suggestions are appreciated!

Comment: Can you post some code that demonstrates what your thunk accomplished?

Comment: @seniorquico, just updated question with code.

Comment: Sorry but I'm having a hard time visualizing what you want to do with redux-observable, could you post what you have tried so far? Even if it is incomplete or doesn't fully function that is easier to help you with than creating it from scratch.

Comment: @paulpdaniels, I just added the code that I used to roughly approximate the thunk flow using redux observable. The issue for me is that I want all of the logic that deals with the `fetchCurrentUser` api call to reside in `fetchCurrentUserEpic`, including response handling (I don't like passing the `payloadNormalizer` as a kind of callback), but I also want a centralized place where everything related to an api call is handled.

Comment: This is prob one of the big reasons I see against adopting redux observable - doesn't seem to be a very lively community :(

Comment: I guess the problem is redux-observable conventions are still in a... hmmm... flux.

Answer (score 0):

I've found [redux-fetch-epic-builder](https://github.com/pcmnac/redux-fetch-epic-builder) (A lib for building "fetch actions" and generic epics handled by redux-observable) to be similar to what you are trying to achieve here (beware it uses rxjs 5, [this guide](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/docs_app/content/guide/v6/migration.md) to rescue). It uses fetch, not axios, but it's easy to replace that. Plus it has transformers for successful/failed actions.

The library is a bit old, but the base idea to overcome boilerplate code is still valid: Generic epic-builder to fetch data with calls to API(s).

I am a novice in React / Redux / RxJS, but the only problem I see with the `redux-fetch-epic-builder` is the way to configure the `client` (in axios terms). That is, I am not fully satisfied with (due to it being not FSA or RSAA):

```
//action creators
const getComments = (id, page = 1) => ({
    type: GET_COMMENTS,
    host: 'http://myblog.com',
    path: `/posts/${id}/comments`,
    query: {
        page,
    },
})
// ...
const epics = [
    buildEpic(GET_COMMENTS),
]
```

but this may still be an elegant way. And the license allow to develop the library further. I have not converted the example from the library documentation to your user-related example, but with react-observable there is certainly no need to introduce a separate "api middleware". (Also, I like `/SUBACTION` better than `_SUBACTION`, but it's trivial to change.)